# How to install a custom boost version in CentOS?

Tags: software-installation, path, libraries, dependencies, boost

I'm trying to compile and install [boost](http://www.boost.org/) 1.54 from source in CentOS.

The documentation is pretty straight forward and there are plenty of tutorials in the internet available ([1](http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.de/2012/11/compiling-and-installing-boost-c.html)) ([2](http://ben-tech.blogspot.de/2013/06/build-boost-for-impala-in-centos-63.html)) ([3](http://gisfromscratch.WordPress.com/2011/12/24/building-boost-on-linux-2/)). This is what I did:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/boost_1_54_0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf boost_1_54_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_54_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
./b2 install --with=all
```

This is compiling and installing boost correctly to `/usr/local/lib` and everything looks fine.

Now I compile other software that requires boost using `gcc` and everything works fine. From my understanding everything should be OK as long as `gcc` finds the required libs.

But now the problem: If I run my compiled binaries I get the following error:

```
./myProgram
  ./myProgramm: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why can the libraries not be found?

In addition I tried:

```
ldconfig
locate boost
  [...]
```

But boost libraries can not be found. I've looked for the path manually, it is:

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
```

I also tried to create symlinks to `/usr/lib` but this doesn't fix this either.

Any ideas? What can I do?

Comment: I'd generally recommend building from a suitably chosen source RPM. What CentOS version are you using?

Comment: CentOS 6.4, I'm not used to this environment, I'm more the Debian/Gentoo guy. I might have a look into the RPMs too.

Comment: I use Debian myself. But rebuilding an RPM is not hard. My recommendation is to find a source rpm for boost 1.54 for some version of CentOS. Presumably a more recent version than you are using. Then adjust for your version as necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `-Wl,-R/usr/local/lib` to the `LDFLAGS` when compiling your program.

`-R` is a linker option (for specifying a runtime linker path) - `-Wl` instructs `gcc` to pass it to `ld`.

With shared libraries you have to make sure that they are found by the linker during compile *and* during runtime (cf. flags `-L` and `-R`).

You can use

```
$ ldd myProgramm
```

to verify if the runtime-linker path was set correctly, i.e. if it can find the needed shared libraries on program start/which shared libraries it will load.

Comment: Setting LDFLAGS at compile time is just working great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I believe you can prefix the running of the executable with the environment variable `LD_LIBRRAY_PATH` and give it the path to the directory which contains the `.so` library.

#### Example

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./myProgram
```

But it sounds like the method you've used to compile the application in question is not correct. I'd need to see your compilation method for `myProgram` to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah that works indeed, thanks. But I guess I will have to recompile it with adjusted LDFLAGS.

Comment: @qdoe - yes max's answer shows howto accomplish that!

Answer (score 0):

Got boost 1.54 version installed in CentOS 7 with the below commands:

```
sudo wget http://repo.enetres.net/enetres.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/enetres.repo
```

Download the lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm from the below link:
ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2010.0/x86_64/media/main/release/lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm

Install the RPM:

```
sudo rpm -ivh lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Install the required boost library version:

```
sudo yum install boost-devel-1.54.0
```

That's it. Have a great day!

rpm link:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)